# $Ae^{\mathrm{i}\omega t}$ assumption for oscillating systems (formal & intuitive)

Tags: fourier-transform, oscillators, differential-equations

When we obtain a system of ODE's for $n$ masses connected with springs (or otherwise obtained by small amplitudes approximation), the next steps are usually

- assuming a solution in form $Ae^{i\omega t}$ with complex $A$
- obtaining and solving an equation of order $2n$ for $n$ degrees of freedom $\rightarrow$ getting the eigenfrequencies

**Why we can assume $Ae^{i\omega t}$ to be a solution?**

This question should be divided in two:

- *Mathematical (formal, proven, ...)*: **Why can we assume this? What are the presumptions and generality? What is the exact connection to fourier-transform?**
- *Physical (intuitive)*: **Why we can assume the harmonic motion?**

Answer (score 1):

**Mathematical assumption**

We assume the solution of the wave equation to be $L^2([a,b])$. Let $e_i$ be any element of a basis of the aforementioned space and $D$ the differential operator whose equation of motion we want to solve. If $D$ is linear (as it is in the case at hand) then $De_i=0$ implies $D(\sum_i c_i e_i)=0$ by linearity.

One basis of $L^2([a,b])$ is composed of the vectors $\{e^{ikx}\}$ for some appropriate $k$. A linear combination of the before converges within the space (under some suitable assumptions) and is referred to as Fourier transform.

**Physical assumption**

Given the underlying hypotheses on how the equation was derived, one expects the solutions to be harmonic with some period $\omega$ and some dispersion relation $k\equiv k(\omega)$. The *easiest* way to construct such a solution is to take sums of sines and cosines, or, equivalently, complex exponentials.

Comment: Thanks! That is a nice answer, but for a continuous system (string). How can this be formulated for a discrete masses?

Comment: There's no requirement in the above for the system to be continuous: what matters are the values that $k$ takes; brutally speaking, replacing the integral with a Fourier sum will do the job just as good.

Comment: And that's the point where I have an intuition but not enough maths. For example: how is wave number defined for the discrete system? If you have simple 2 coupled oscillators, what is the $k$? It would by my pleasure to reward a detailed answer by a bounty. If you think that I should rephrase the question, I could.

Comment: The allowed values of $k$ depend on the boundary conditions posed on the differential equation; there's a whole bunch of literature and standard exercised showing what $k$ is according to the domains and the initial conditions; have a look, otherwise pose a related questions (maybe on the maths page).

Comment: I don't think we fully understand each other (which is probably my mistake). I don't have an equation but set of them (ODE's). How there is such a thing as boundary condition? On a string (wave equation, PDE) is it crystal clear.

Comment: Well, PDE or ODE always come with boundary conditions for the solution to be unique (ODE), hence you must have them or fix them by yourself (according to the specifications of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

The solution implies that all motion is "in phase". This is the characteristic of a standing wave, as opposed to a traveling wave. But in fact any traveling wave can be decomposed as the superposition of two standing waves (one coming and the other going). So the assumption of a series of standing waves is general enough to solve this problem.